# Odoo11 : Add attribute to an existing kanban view element

Tags: inheritance, odoo-11, qweb

I am working with `Odoo 11` and I have inherited the `product.template kanban view`. I want to add a class to the div element with the following class `oe_kanban_global_click`. I have used the two following snippets but neither is working (nothing is added to the div element).

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_kanban_global_click']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="t-attf-class" separator=" " add="oe_kanban_color_#{record.x_alert_qty_reached.raw_value}"/>
</xpath>
```

and

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_kanban_global_click']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="t-attf-class">oe_kanban_color_#{record.x_alert_qty_reached.raw_value}"</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Any help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the class attribute to an empty string.

The following example inherit the product template kanban view to change the class attribute:

```
<record id="product_template_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Product.template.product.kanban</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//templates" position="before">
            <field name="x_alert_qty_reached"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_kanban_global_click']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class"></attribute>
            <attribute name="t-attf-class">oe_kanban_color_#{record.x_alert_qty_reached.raw_value} oe_kanban_card oe_kanban_global_click</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: thank you. It worked even without this

<xpath expr="//templates" position="before">
            <field name="x_alert_qty_reached"/>
 </xpath>

Comment: I added the field before the `templates` tag because Odoo raise an error: `Error: QWeb2 - template['kanban-box']: Runtime Error: TypeError: dict.record.x_alert_qty_reached is undefined`.